# How to create a new derived column in a pandas dataframe new column using only notnull vaues

Tags: python, pandas

Often I want to map a function to a column containing nulls, and I find my self having to write some sort of logic checking for nulls. For example:

```
In [656]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.DataFrame(['Apple Pear',np.nan,'Orange Banana'], columns = ['fruits'])
df['first_fruit'] = df.fruits.map(lambda x: (type(x) != float and min(x.split())) or np.nan)
df
Out[656]: 
          fruits first_fruit
0     Apple Pear       Apple
1            NaN         NaN
2  Orange Banana      Banana
```

This type of thing always feels somewhat clunky to me. Is there a preferred way to apply a function to only the nonnull rows of a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [isnull](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) or [notnull](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.notnull.html#pandas.notnull) methods to filter out non-null elements of a column

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.DataFrame(['Apple Pear',np.nan,'Orange Banana'], columns = ['fruits'])
df['first_fruit'] = df.fruits[~df.fruits.isnull()].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
# or: df['first_fruit'] = df.fruits[df.fruits.notnull()].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
```

This will create a new `first_fruit` column, and fill it with nulls (`np.nan`) where `fruits` was null (`np.nan`)

```
          fruits first_fruit
0     Apple Pear       Apple
1            NaN         NaN
2  Orange Banana      Orange
```

I don't think `type(x) != float` is good idiom to use in this case (because python is dynamically typed, you should not need to validate input type to a function), nor does it actually work for float columns in pandas data frame.

e.g.

```
df['prices'] = [1.0, np.nan, 2.0]
df.prices.apply(lambda x: type(x) == float)
```

prints out

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: prices, dtype: bool
```

If you must check parameter type, use `isinstance`

```
df.prices.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, float))
```

prints out

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: prices, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I had initially tried something like this but didn't realise that you only have to apply the filter on the RHS of the assignment and not the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc` and `notnull` to mask the df and the vectorised `str` methods to `split` the strings:

```
In [34]:

df= pd.DataFrame(['Apple Pear',np.nan,'Orange Banana'], columns = ['fruits'])
df['first_fruit'] = df.loc[df['fruits'].notnull(),'fruits'].str.split().str[0]
df
Out[34]:
          fruits first_fruit
0     Apple Pear       Apple
1            NaN         NaN
2  Orange Banana      Orange
```